# Strange behavior while page navigation in wp 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am making a Wp 8.1 app.

I have this "reader" page. Its constructor is -

```
    public Reader()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
        initalizeTimers();
        initAd();
    }
```

and the onNvaigatedTo

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        HardwareButtons.BackPressed += Hardware_backPressedLocal;
        var x = (Tuple<int, string, Global.FileType>)e.Parameter;

        //load settings here
        loadColorSchemes();
        setStatusBarColor();

        if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
        {
            readerVm.refreshWebView();
            return;
        }

        if (x != null)
        {
            initalizeReader(x);
        }
    }
```

The `initalizeReader()` is an async method. The page has a grid in front for showing the wait msg, and the initializeReader method hides that grid.

**Problem:**

On tapping a button which calls the `Frame.Navigate()` method to the reader page, sometimes the reader page loads with waiting grid which hides after sometime (expected) and at other times the UI freezes and then the reader page loads with waiting grid already hidden. And 70-80 % time the UI freezes.

Can you tell whats going wrong here? And how to fix it?

Comment: What is the code of initializeReader() method?

Comment: @EldarDordzhiev the most costly method is FileIO.ReadTextAsync(), and others are loading values from LocalSettings.

Comment: @aclab doesn't matter, just past here your code. That would help.

Comment: The freeze is most likely due to a deadlock. A good way to understand what's happening is to press the "pause" button of the debugger when the application freezes, then check the callstack to see what the thread is waiting for

Answer (score 0):

Try to call your method `initalizeReader(x);` when the event `Loaded` from the page raised.
Also, if this method calls some async functions, call them asynchronously also.